# Set custom name to QWeb report in ODOO

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I have created qweb report for **account.invoice** model in ODOO.

**Problem:**

While we download report in pdf it named as **module_name.report_name** like in my case it is

> **"custom_reports_ept.report_export_invoice"**.
>
> What I want to do is to set downloadable pdf name to **"Export
>   Invoice"** or **"Invoice VDG290-15-16" (VDG290-15-16 is invoice Number)"**.

How could I do this ?

Here is my xml code,

```xml
<report 
    string="Export Invoice" 
    id="account.invoice_export" 
    model="account.invoice" 
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="custom_reports_ept.report_export_invoice" 
    file="custom_reports_ept.report_export_invoice" 
/>
```

Here is the qweb template.

```xml
    <template id="report_export_invoice">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="oe_structure"/>
                    <!-- report body -->
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
     </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some search on this point,

1. In our default odoo we have report module,
2. got to controllers --> main.py
3. you can find this object `def report_download(self, data, token)`:
4. in this function "docids" variables, using this you can get find id of invoice record.
5. `reportname` field is contain report name
6. use this condition:

   if reportname == 'sale.report_saleorder':
       #browse invoice object here and generate new name as per your requirement